# Making table cells a block element

Tags: html, css, cells

I'm currently tasked with making a mobile style sheet for my works website and I've hit a wall with some of the final stages.

My main constraint is that I can't edit the source HTML and have to work with the source provided.

I want to make a table that contains buttons respond when it hits 450px wide by dropping the buttons (table cells) to it's own row. I can do this simply via `divs` but not `tables`. I've created a simple example of what I want to do http://test.aboutcher.co.uk/so/tables.html but I have no idea how this effect can be achieved in the table.

I know tables are a bad idea for layouts but I cannot change this in the source so have to fight my way with it.

**Edit**
I've found my issue, there's a non cell that isn't getting the `display:block` style applied in the source causing the other two that are receiving the style to ignore the display:block.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not an Ideal way. but as I see it, I think you can create another table row, and hide it initially by giving a display none; and then use CSS media query, where you set the specify the width: XXpx; and set the top 2nd coloumn to `display: none;` and bottom table colomn to `display : block;`

Hope that makes sense

```
@media (max-device-width = 400px) {
  .second-column{display:block;}
.first-column{display:none;}
}
```

Comment: I've found my issue, there's a non cell that isn't getting the display:block style applied in the source causing the other two that are recieving the style to ignore the display:block.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define that your `td` is `display:block` and manipulate them as your `div`. Have a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/68EQK/

Comment: I've found my issue, there's a non cell that isn't getting the display:block style applied in the source causing the other two that are recieving the style to ignore the display:block.